# Read ascii charactres and ints from file (java)

Tags: java, int, ascii

I'm doing a project where I my code has to be the most efficient possible, and I need to read ascii chars and ints from a file. The problem (I think) is that when I read chars it reads in UTF8 beacuse it only reads half the times it should.

I tried with DataInputStream but it doesnt work. Also I check the RandomAccessFile but it reads in UTF8. The Scanner throws an InputMismatchException when I tried to read two bytes and convert them to char.

Is it that the only option is to do this by hand?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to verify, your choice of language was forced to be Java, correct?  Java is not typically the choice language for efficient manipulations.

Comment: Just once, I'd like to see someone say that their code has to be the most easily understood by other people.

Comment: Check out the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93423/java-reading-an-ascii-file-with-filechannel-and-bytearrays  The trick is the CharacterSet.

Comment: If you show your code, people can help you modify it to work.

Comment: @BlackVegetable Yes, it has be java :p

Answer (score 3):

Read one byte at once. It will be the value you want. For example, with [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) `read()` method:

> read() Reads a byte of data from this file. The byte is returned as an
>   integer in the range 0 to 255 (0x00-0x0ff). This method blocks if no
>   input is yet available.

Example:

`int asciiValue randomAccessFile.read();`

Then you can cast `ìnt` to `char`

`char character = (char) asciiValue;`

Comment: Yeah, I'll do it with a DataInputStream with a buffer because I need to be efficient. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem is. The thing is that when you write chars and ints using BufferedWriter, it converts all to char, which makes it impossible to read ints as a type directly from file. I'll try writing with a DataOutputStream, using the methods to direclty write ints and chars.